# start with Connect by prior in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

Can anyone please help in converting below start with connect by ORACLE query to a Redshift query. I believe start with is not working in Redshift.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   mrcompanyid || locationid location_lkp_id
   , (SELECT 
         t2.locationid
      FROM 
         dwh.dmn_me_location t2 
      START WITH t2.locationid = t1.locationid AND t2.mrcompanyid=t1.mrcompanyid
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR t2.locationparentid=t2.locationid
      GROUP BY T2.MRCOMPANYID,T2.LOCATIONID,T2.LOCATIONTYPE
      HAVING 
         LOCATIONTYPE='COUNTRY' AND 
         T2.MRCOMPANYID=T1.MRCOMPANYID
      ) location_country_id
FROM
   dwh.dmn_me_location t1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desire results.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read.